# jquery mobile checkbox not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile. Someone else wrote some code for me but it's not 100% working. There are four checkboxes : All, A1, A2, A3.

1. Click All - all 3 are selected
2. then uncheck one of them, All is off
3. Click All again - all 3 are selected but All itself is not, it has to be selected again.

So the code to unselect All is not working
http://jsfiddle.net/chiti/M366L/1/

I did not write this code but I have to fix it, and I tried both these versions and neither worked.

```
$('#Select_All_1').find('span.ui-icon-shadow').attr('class','ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow');
$('#Select_All_1').filter(':checkbox').prop('checked',true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

thanks

Comment: in step3, you want all other boxes to uncheck or want the `all` box to be checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed and simplified your JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#ALLF").click(function()
    {
        var thisChecked = $("#ALLF").prop("checked");
        $("[id^=CheckA]").prop("checked", thisChecked).checkboxradio("refresh");
    });


    $("[id^=CheckA]").click(function()
    {
        var allChecked = true;
        $.each($("[id^=CheckA]"), function(index, current)
        {
            if ($(current).prop("checked") === false)
                allChecked = false;
        });

        $("#ALLF").prop("checked", allChecked).checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M366L/14/)**

Comment: Thanks so much, however I should have sent all the details, this is only one of four sets of fields, there is also B1...B3 with its own Select All, as well as C, D etc. How do I make this apply only to the CheckA1 options?

Comment: @GamChai: I have updated my example. However, do not duplicate this code for your B/C/D checkboxes. Use a different ID for the "select all" checkbox (ie: `selectall_CheckA`), and use that to select the relative group of checkboxes (use a jQuery selector)...

Comment: Excellent! I created new functions so it can be reused for all four blocks http://jsfiddle.net/M366L/16/